# R: Error in textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, terminology = article_words) : nrow(data) > 1 is not TRUE

Tags: r, text, nlp, tidyr

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to learn how to summarize text articles by using the following website: https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/tidy-text-summarization-using-textrank/

As per the instructions, I copied the code from the website (I used some random PDF I found online):

```
library(tidyverse)
## Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)
library(rvest)
## Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 3.6.2

url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/hamlet_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"


article <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('div[class="padded"]') %>%
  html_text()


article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words <- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")
```

Everything works fine up to here.

The following part is where the problem is:

```
 article_summary <- textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, 
                                      terminology = article_words)

Error in textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, terminology = article_words) : 
  nrow(data) > 1 is not TRUE
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Is the above procedure not intended for "pdf" files?

Is this a possible solution - what if I copy/paste the entire text from this pdf and assign it to the "article" object, and then carry on with the rest of the code?

e.g. `article <- "blah blah blah ..... blah blah blah"`

Thanks

Comment: This `html_nodes('div[class="padded"]')` doesn't match anything so everything from there has no data e.g. empty tibble hence your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you shared reads the data from a webpage. `div[class="padded"]` is specific to the webpage that they were reading. It will not work for any other webpage nor the pdf from which you are trying to read the data. You can use `pdftools` package to read data from pdf.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)

url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/hamlet_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words <- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")

article_summary <- textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, terminology = article_words)
```

Comment: Thank you @ronakshah! Can you please take a look at this question when you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thank you!